# How do you implement requeuing for a SLURM array?

Tags: slurm

I'm running an array job on a HPC using SLURM with the following command:

```
sbatch --array=0-9 my_task.batch
```

If one of the tasks in the array job fails, I want to requeue that specific job (not the entire array).

How would I go about doing this?

I've seen a suggestion that I should add `#SBATCH --requeue` to the header in my_task.batch, or that the submission command becomes `sbatch --array=0-9 --requeue my_task.batch`.

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with the specifics of SLURM to know which (if either) of these I want!

If it helps, I'm running SLURM 18.08.3

Answer (score 0):

That is not a feature that Slurm offers out of the box. Fortunately, there are workflow management tools such as [atools](https://atools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that help. That tool allows you to re-run only failed jobs, get summarised view of the whole array, etc.